# How to Assign a Playlist Item to Expression media Player?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I am able to aassign a playlist to MediaPlayer like follwoing:

```
myMediaElement.Playlist = playList;
```

Where playList is the collection of `PlaylistItem`.

But here my question is how can we assign just a playListItem to `myMediaElement`. For Example:

```
myMediaElement.Playlist = playList.Items[0];
```

I don not want to used `myMediaElement.GoToPlaylistItem(index);`

Thanks,

Subhen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok , I was not able to assign directly the playlist Item but created by taking another temporary playlist.

Have a look [here](http://blog.subhendu.info/index.php/how-to-assign-a-playlistitem-to-expression-mediaplayer-in-silverlight/) and let me know if there are any alternate methods or some better way to make it happen.

Thanks,

Subhen